# How to change order of arguments within a cycle in python

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda, arguments

I'm trying to improve some code by transforming 2 very similar for cycles in only one. Basicaly the only difference between those cycles is the order the arguments are given to a function.
My code is something like this:

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
         sample_func(i,j)
```

And then I do the same thing but changing the order of the function arguments:

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
         sample_func(j,i)
```

Is there a simple way I can turn this cycle into a function that receives a argument that tells the order of the arguments that are input in sample_func?
I hope I was clear and thank you in advance!

EDIT:

```
for i in range(dimensions[1]):
    count_b = 0
    count_w = 0
    len_esp = len(esp(board)[0][i])
    add_esp = 0
    for esp in len_esp[i]:
        add_esp += esp        
    for k in range(1, dimensions[1] + 1):
        if board_value(board, create_coordinate(i+1, k)) == 2:
            count_b += 1
        elif board_value(board, create_coordinate(i+1, k)) == 1:
            count_w += 1
        else:
            return False           
    if add_esp != count_b or count_2 < (len_esp - 1):
        return False

for i in range(dimensions[1]):
    count_b = 0
    count_w = 0
    len_esp = len(esp(board)[1][i])
    add_esp = 0
    for esp in len_esp[i]:
        add_esp += esp        
    for k in range(1, dimensions[1] + 1):
        if board_value(board, create_coordinate(k, i+1)) == 2:
            count_b += 1
        elif board_value(board, create_coordinate(k, i+1)) == 1:
            count_w += 1
        else:
            return False           
    if add_esp != count_b or count_2 < (len_esp - 1):
        return False
return True
```

Comment: are those 2 functions the same ? if yes just reverse the fors no need to remove 2 lines of code or call both functions in one loop

Comment: The sample_func is the same, but because of the long nature of my original cycles and the only difference between them being that, the way i want to call the arguments, I was thinking that it would reduce my code if I just created a function with those for cycles

Comment: Does `sample_func(j, i)` have to be called after all of the `sample_func(i, j)` or can you just add them both into the same loop?

Comment: what happens after each loop - it looks like you dont use the returned values, so simply changing the order of the parms and calling both in same loop should be fine, unless there is some magic accumulation or something in the function that is order dependant

Comment: I have to call them separatly, because this cycle already receives a list of lists as argument, and this lists are different.

Comment: then no you cant simplify the calls - they are on different entities

Comment: I'll edit my op to try to be more specific

Comment: are you trying to simplify the code or reduce the run time?

Comment: I'm trying to simplify the code, because this two cycles are very similar. Only the way I want to go through my "board" (which is a lists of lists) is different from one cycle to the other. I added an edit to try to be clearer

Comment: What is the function signature? def func(arg1, arg2, etc)...what is before the 'for' loops you show above?

Comment: The create_coordinates function? that is a simples function that receives 2 arguments, the line and the column of the coordinate and return a tuple with them

Comment: Your code above starts with 'for' and ends with 'return'...but no function definition? I'm expecting something like def my_func(args) before the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pack, reverse if required, expand.

```
for k in (1, -1):
  sample_func(*(i, j)[::k])
```

Comment: That solved my problem! Thank you very much Ignacio!

Comment: Amazing how a simple list indexing can be useful ...!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use python decorator method in your code. For example:

```
 def loop(seq):
    def _loop(function):
        def __loop(*args,**kw):
            x,y=args[0],args[1]
            if seq==True:
                function(x,y)
            else:
                function(y,x)
        return __loop
    return _loop

@loop(True)
def loop1(x,y):
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            printFunc(i,j)

loop1(3,5)


@loop(False)
def loop1(x,y):
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            printFunc(i,j)

loop1(3,5)
```